# Install chrome extension with Custom text

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When installing a chrome extension from the website, we are prompted with the alert box [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8f0F.png).

Is there a way to change the text in the alert box from "Add Extension" to "Add"?

Answer (score 0):

No, you have no power on the system alert box. In your website/application you could use some modal alert box which emulate it but you can not change the Chrome's box in any way. (unless you work at Google Chrome department :P ) It is easy to understand that it would not be much safe.